# Write function's returning value to specified variable in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have to write a function that returns length of the specified variable to the second one. Actually, I don't know how to do it. I had several ideas like `set %~2=%len%` or `set len=call :parse_to_tokens %input%`, but they didn't work.

```
:length
set string=%~1
set len=0
:loop
if defined string (
   set string=%string:~1%
   set /a len+=1
   goto loop
)
:: The return statement or something.
exit /b 0

set /p input=""
call :parse_to_tokens %input% %len%
echo %len%
:: Prints input length.
```

Comment: `set %~2=%len%` actually works, but you have to `call %input% len`, because you don't want to assign to the content `%len%`, but to the variable `len`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.

Comment: @Stephan, also, how can I make `string` and `len` variables local and keep the return statement?

Comment: Take a look at [this function](https://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.strLen).